# MPI convention for index of rows and columns

Tags: mpi, ipc, fortran90, contiguous

I am using MPI for solving PDE. For this, I breakdown the 2D domain into different cells (size of each of these cells is "`xcell,ycell`" with `xcell = size_x_domain/(number of X subdomains)` and `ycell = size_y_domain/(number of Y subdomains)`.

So, I am running the code with `number of processes = (number of X subdomains)*(number of Y subdomains)`

The gain relatively to sequential version is that I communicate between each process representing the sub-domains.

Here a figure illustrating my breakdown with 8 processes (2 subdomains for X and 4 for Y) :

[image]

(`xs,xe`) represent `x_start` and `x_end` of the cell,
(`ys,ye`) represent `y_start` and `y_end` of the cell

I would like to know if I have to set, into `x(i,j)` array, **i the index as row index** and **j as column index** ?

Is it a general rule to put the first index for row and the second one for column ? ( for example, in C, Fortran and Matlab language or maybe more)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: in `x(i,j)` `i` is always the row and `j` is always the column. "Fortran is column major" means that in memory `x(1,0)` is next to `x(0,0)`. On the other hand, C is row major, which means that in `real x[2][2]`, `x(0,1)` is in memory next to `x(0,0)`.

Comment: -@GillesGouaillardet ok, so what have I got to do to fix my issue with Fortran and row_type that I have defined ? When you say " in x(i,j) i is always the row and j is always the column", you talk about for both C and Fortran languages ?

Comment: correct, "always" here means both C and Fortran

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but maybe try having a different flag for all 4 of the communications.