# Convention with rows and columns index for most of languages

Tags: c, matlab, matrix, fortran, row-major-order

Following the question on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087715/mpi-convention-for-index-of-rows-and-columns), Is it a general rule (I mean for a majority of languages) to consider, for a 2 dimensional array "**x(i,j)**", the first index **i** for the index of rows and index **j** for the index of columns ?

I know that Fortran is column major, C Language is row major, and for both, it seems that classical convention is i = rows and j = columns, doesn't it ?

Moreover, could anyone tell me if Matlab is row or column major ?

Comment: In Matlab the first index is row and the second index is column.

Comment: No: Fortran views it one way and C the other.  The two views are opposites.

Comment: MATLAB is [column major](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html#f22019) due to its Fortran roots.

Comment: C doesn't have such a thing as a two dimensional array.  If you're thinking of an array of arrays, that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding. There is no relation between how raw data is allocated in memory and the higher-level representation that the raw data is supposed to model.

C does not place any meaning to the indices in `[i][j]`, this just specifies how the data is allocated in memory, not how it is presented to a user. `i` could be rows or it could be columns, this is for the programmer to specify in their application.

However, C does allocate the right-most dimension together in memory, example:

```
int arr[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {1,2,3} };

+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   1   |   2   |   3   |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

This means that the preferred way to iterate over this matrix is:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<2; i++)
  for(size_t j=0; j<3; j++)
    arr[i][j] = x;
```

Because this order gives the fastest memory access, as far as cache memory is concerned. But the language does not enforce this order, we can iterate with `j` in the outer loop and the program will work just as fine (just slower).

Nor can we tell if this matrix is supposed to be a 2x3 or a 3x2.

Answer (score 1):

For MATLAB, the first index is the row and the second is the column. But arrays are stored internally in column-major order (very early versions of MATLAB were implemented in FORTRAN; when it was originally commercialised it was mostly converted into C, but kept that convention).

Comment: are you saying if I do: ` A = [1 2;3 4;5 6]` that is actually internally stored as `1,3,5,2,4,6` ?

Comment: answering myself, that indeed seems to be the case as matlab allows a single (flat) index on a multidimensional array and for example `A(3) -> 5`

Comment: Correct - that's called linear indexing in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered [here](https://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=C_vs_Fortran_memory_order).

Quote:

> In summary:
>
> The "shape" of the memory is exactly the same in C and Fortran even though language differences make it look different due to reversed array indexing.
>
> If you don't iterate through a Fortran array in k,j,i order, you'll access memory out of order and negatively impact your cache performance.

Comment: what does the "shape" of memory even mean?  Data is ultimately effectively stored "flat" and what's relevant here is the indexing scheme so Its not clear what point they are making.